# .htaccess file not working?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, opencart

I am using the default .htaccess file of opencart below, I manually added the last 2 lines.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} diger_olcu_aletleri
RewriteRule ^diger_olcu_aletleri$ http://www.hirdavatdeposu.com/diger-olcu-aletleri
```

I have checked using the website (http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) and it changes my url

> diger_olcu_aletleri

to

> diger-olcu-aletleri

as expected, however it does not work in my website. What can be the problem ?

Below is my complete .htaccess file.

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} diger_olcu_aletleri
RewriteRule ^diger_olcu_aletleri$ http://www.hirdavatdeposu.com/diger-olcu-aletleri

### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_input_time 200
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last line of the OpenCart `.htaccess` rules basically catches anything and then stops. Try your two lines just after the `RewriteBase` line as that should work. The `.htaccess` file is checked line by line and the `L` in `[L,QSA]` on the last OC line means to stop after that line is run

Answer (score 0):

We had a different issue where OpenCart SEO Urls weren't being displayed. All Google searches pointed us to enabling mod_rewrite.  The solution to our problem was slightly different than what others have posted, so I thought I would share in a place that others might find as well.

Our platform:

> -Linux version 2.6.32-042stab111.11
>   (root@kbuild-rh6-x64.eng.sw.ru)     (gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red
>   Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC) )     #1 SMP Tue Sep 1 18:19:12 MSK 2015
>
> -CentOS release 6.8 (Final)   -Kernel \r on an \m

Service provider: railsplayground.com

We correctly created our .htaccess file as OpenCart specifies
cp .htaccess.txt .htaccess

But this **broke all pages** that OpenCart showed us.

After much gnashing of teeth, we started to comment out different lines in the .htaccess file.

It turned out the **first line**

```
         Options +FollowSymlinks
```

Broke our links.  Removing this line entirely made the SEO URLS work just fine.

Also, be sure not to have a / either before or after the SEO URL.

Hope this helps someone out.